# Como obtener el value del checkbox, que al hacer click muestre otro grupo de checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql-server, checkbox

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un problema con enviar el value de mi checkbox, como se muestra en la imagen solo se visualiza el primer grupo de chekbox, ya que solo envia el primer value.

Este es mi codigo de html donde llamo a la base de datos y muestro los laboratorios. para cada laboratorio hay un grupo de analisis. Para esto se pueden seleccionar varios laboratorios como varios analisis.

para cada checkbox de laboratorio se ingresa un value que es el id del laboratorio.

```
<div class="mb-3"> 
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">AREA LABORATORIO *</label>
          </div>
          <?php
                $cultivo = $dataBase->prepare('VISTA_LABORATORIO_ACTIVA');
                $cultivo->execute();
        
                foreach ($cultivo as $tipo){
                  
                  ?>
          <div class="mb-3 form-check form-switch divAreaLab">
          
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="areaLab" id="areaLab" value="<?php echo $tipo['ID_AREA_LABORATORIO']; ?>" onchange="showContent()">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault"><?php echo $tipo['DETALLE']; ?></label>
            
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3" id="content">
            <span id="viewTipoAnalsis"></span>
          </div>
        <?php } ?>
```

este es mi script donde realiza la funcion, y aqui recibe el value del checkbox y lo envia a otra funcion para poder visualizar los tipos de analisis. aqui es donde solo me esta enviando el primer value. cuando deveria de enviar cada value por serparado dependiendo de la cantidad de checkbox de laboratorio que tenga.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showContent() {
        element = document.getElementById("content");
        check = document.getElementById("areaLab");

        if (check.checked) {
          tipoAnalisis($('#areaLab').val());
          element.style.display='block';
        }else{
          element.style.display='none';
        }
    };
</script>
```

este es el script para ver los tipos de analisis, recibe el idAreaLab, que es el value del chexbox. con este no tengo problemas funciona correctamente, pero solo me recibe el primer value del primer checkbox.\

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function tipoAnalisis(idAreaLab){
  
  var parametro = {
    'idAreaLab' : idAreaLab,
  };

  $.ajax({

    type : 'post',
    url : '../ajax/viewTipoAnalisis.php',
    data : parametro,

    success : function(r){

      console.log(parametro);
      $('#viewTipoAnalsis').html(r);
      
    }

  })

}

</script>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como se muestra en la consola, solo recibe el primer value

en pocas palabras quiero que envie su value correspondiente y me visualice cada grupo de checkbox correctamente.

cualquier sugerencia/solucion seria genial.

Comment: te falta poder capturar el evento del click(), te recomiendo que mires la documentacion de addEventLisener

Answer (score 0):

En este caso entendo que usas algo como bootstrap o materialize, pero espero que entiendas el codigo que te voy a dar;

Lo que has de hacer es esperar a que se haga click en el checkbox para ver si esta checked, una vez checkeado, el atributo checked pasara a ser true,y se ejecutara esa funcion.

```js
            //buscamos el checkbox con el id checkbox
            var checkbox = document.getElementById("checkbox");
            //esperamos a que se haga un click
            checkbox.addEventListener("click", function () {
              //si el checkbox esta seleccionado
              if (checkbox.checked) {
                //cambiamos el color del fondo
               alert("hola estoy checkeado");
              } else {
                //si no esta seleccionado
                alert("hola no estoy checkeado");
              }
            });
```

```html
Checkbox<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
```

En tu caso es asi:

```
//buscamos el checkbox con el id checkbox
            var checkbox = document.getElementById("checkbox");
            //esperamos a que se haga un click
            checkbox.addEventListener("click", function () {
              //si el checkbox esta seleccionado
              if (checkbox.checked) {
                tipoAnalisis($('#areaLab').val());
      element.style.display='block';
              } else {
                element.style.display='none';
              }
            });
```